# Bootstrap 4 sass two gradient colors to navbar links hover not working

Tags: sass, hover, navbar, gradient, bootstrap-4

i'm really new to sass and i have search a lot for this i cloud not find any solution, help me

i have created bootstrap 4 navbar with gradient background and gradient navbar links its working perfectly and again i add gradient font color to a:hover its working but also if i add gradient background color to a:hover its not working, only showing 'a' link background-color gradient but not 'a' font gradient

Any help will be appreciated, and thank you in advance.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQdNx.png)

[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByG21.png)

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBarItems" aria-controls="navbarText"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBarItems">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Books</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Guest</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link active">Contact us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**SASS**

```
@mixin gold-gradient(){
background: rgb(249, 206, 112);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 0%, rgba(197, 154, 38, 1) 50%, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 100%, rgba(123, 90, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 0%, rgba(197, 154, 38, 1) 50%, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 100%, rgba(123, 90, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 0%, rgba(197, 154, 38, 1) 50%, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 100%, rgba(123, 90, 0, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9ce70', endColorstr='#7b5a00', GradientType=1);
}

@mixin red-gradient($dir-1: left,
$dir-2: right) {
    background: rgb(153, 10, 34);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient($dir-1, rgba(153, 10, 34, 1) 8%, rgba(200, 9, 54, 1) 50%, rgba(211, 31, 31, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient($dir-1, rgba(153, 10, 34, 1) 8%, rgba(200, 9, 54, 1) 50%, rgba(211, 31, 31, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to $dir-2, rgba(153, 10, 34, 1) 8%, rgba(200, 9, 54, 1) 50%, rgba(211, 31, 31, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#990a22', endColorstr='#d31f1f', GradientType=1);
}

@mixin gold-text-gradient() {
    background: rgb(249, 206, 112);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 0%, rgba(197, 154, 38, 1) 50%, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 100%, rgba(123, 90, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 0%, rgba(197, 154, 38, 1) 50%, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 100%, rgba(123, 90, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 0%, rgba(197, 154, 38, 1) 50%, rgba(249, 206, 112, 1) 100%, rgba(123, 90, 0, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9ce70', endColorstr='#7b5a00', GradientType=1);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

@mixin red-text-gradient() {
    background: rgb(153, 10, 34);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(153, 10, 34, 1) 8%, rgba(200, 9, 54, 1) 50%, rgba(211, 31, 31, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(153, 10, 34, 1) 8%, rgba(200, 9, 54, 1) 50%, rgba(211, 31, 31, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(153, 10, 34, 1) 8%, rgba(200, 9, 54, 1) 50%, rgba(211, 31, 31, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#990a22', endColorstr='#d31f1f', GradientType=1);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.navbar {
    @include red-gradient();
    .navbar-nav li a {
        @include gold-text-gradient;
    }
    .navbar-nav li a:hover {
        @include red-text-gradient();
        @include gold-gradient();
    }
}
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/samzalahi/pen/LOpXoy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it worked for me.

```
.navbar {
   @include red-gradient();
   .navbar-nav li a {
       @include gold-text-gradient;
   }

   .navbar-nav{ 
       a:hover {
         @include red-text-gradient();
       }
       li:hover{
         @include gold-gradient();
       } 
    } 
}
```

The problem was that you were setting this gradient to the text (`<a>` in this case) and not to the container of this text (`<li>`).

Comment: yah, i have tried this one before i post this question, but can i archive this by normal css way which is giving a:hover{color:#fff; background:#000} as gradient color

Comment: I guess you can't because you need to access to the parent of a:hover{} in this case and I don't know the way in Sass. But I thing that the solution that I gave you it's efficient and it's working well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,